# Steamworks checking if a user is logged in

Tags: c++, steam, unreal-engine4, steamworks-api

So the code that I've been using to get a user's Steam ID is:

```
CSteamID uid = SteamUser()->GetSteamID();
uint64 pid = uid.ConvertToUint64();
std::ostringstream sin;
sin << pid;
std::string s = sin.str();
return s.c_str();
```

This works just fine, but when a user is not logged into Steam, this crashes.

> Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)

---

Does Steam provide a function that I can use to check if the user is logged in before running code that depends on the user being logged in? Or is there some sort of try/catch block I can use here to make sure that this does not break and return false if the user is not logged in?

Comment: Find out why it crashes. Is `SteamUser()` a NULL pointer? If so, there's your answer.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit The exact error is `Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)`

Comment: You should use a debugger. That is not "the exact error" :)

Comment: @LightningRacisinOrbit Well Unreal Engine doesn't give me anything better than that, except for a call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Lightning Racis in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightning-racis-in-obrit). A simple nullptr check fixed it.

```
if(SteamUser() == nullptr)
    return false;
```