# Check if Steam is running and user is logged in

Tags: c#, steam

In a nutshell I want to check if Steam is running and the user is logged in. I could only find docu about the web-api which would be the wrong point to start I think.

I don't even need a code example, I just need a hint to the right direction and where to start. I heard about an OpenID implementation in Steam itself but I don't have a clue if it would be the right place to start.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Im sure the process of the login form differs from the main one. So just check if the right process is running. If not, check for the window-name. You could also check if there is a connection to the steam servers up. I hope the goal you are trying to reach is legal.

Comment: I can ensure that it is legal of course. It's going to be for an Arma 3 Launcher which will check prerequisites to start the game properly.

Comment: @C4ud3x How would illegal actions benefit from knowing the basic information of steam running and that logged in... *edit* any more than legal things.

Comment: Ok, so it's the same process but checking the window title should be enough for this. Will test this out. Edit: Huge thanks to the downvoters.

Comment: @Jacobr365 This could be the `!= null` check. I guess we both know this check takes place in the beginning for most of the times.

Comment: @chris579 Im currently not at home. If your question persists Ill check that out in about 2 hours personally.

Comment: Here i think this may be your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854767/steamworks-checking-if-a-user-is-logged-in

Comment: @Jacobr365 Well they use steamworks api and unreal engine which is not really helpful for me. However thanks for the point.

Comment: @C4ud3x Getting the title of the window doesn't works, it's always String.Empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am aware that this is a somewhat older question, but I stumbled upon it looking for an answer myself. I have found a way to do it although it is in C++, it is however perfectly translateable to C#.

**Pseudo code**

```
string SteamExePath = RegistryKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Valve\\Steam\\SteamExe");
while RegistryKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Valve\\Steam\\ActiveProcess\\ActiveUser") == 0
{
    RegisterForRegistryChange("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Valve\\Steam\\ActiveProcess");

    StartProcess(SteamExePath);

    WaitForRegistryChange();
}
```

**C++ code**

*Util.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include "Shared.h"

#define EXCEPTION(message, ...) throw std::runtime_error(Shared::stringFormat(Shared::stringFormat("%s: %s", __FUNCTION__, message), __VA_ARGS__));
#define EXCEPTION_LAST_ERROR(message, ...) throw std::runtime_error(Shared::stringFormat(Shared::stringFormat("%s: %s\nSystem error code: %u", __FUNCTION__, message, GetLastError()), __VA_ARGS__));
#define EXCEPTION_LAST_ERROR2(message, lastError, ...) throw std::runtime_error(Shared::stringFormat(Shared::stringFormat("%s: %s\nSystem error code: %u", __FUNCTION__, message, lastError), __VA_ARGS__));

namespace Shared
{
    template<typename ... Args>
    std::string stringFormat(const std::string &format, Args ...args)
    {
        size_t size = std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, format.c_str(), args...) + 1;
        std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[size]);
        std::snprintf(buf.get(), size, format.c_str(), args...);

        return std::string(buf.get(), buf.get() + size - 1);
    }

    template<typename ... Args>
    std::wstring stringFormat(const std::wstring &format, Args ...args)
    {
        size_t size = std::swprintf(nullptr, 0, format.c_str(), args...) + 1;
        std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> buf(new wchar_t[size]);
        std::swprintf(buf.get(), size, format.c_str(), args...);

        return std::wstring(buf.get(), buf.get() + size - 1);
    }

    void getExecutionPath(std::wstring &path);
}
```

*Process.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

namespace Shared
{
    class Process
    {
        public:
            Process(
                const std::wstring &path,
                const std::wstring &arguments,
                LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes,
                LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes,
                bool inheritHandles, 
                DWORD creationFlags,
                LPVOID environment,
                const std::wstring &currentDirectory,
                const STARTUPINFOEXW &startupInfo);
            Process(
                const std::wstring &&path,
                const std::wstring &&arguments,
                LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes,
                LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes,
                bool inheritHandles, 
                DWORD creationFlags,
                LPVOID environment,
                const std::wstring &&currentDirectory,
                const STARTUPINFOEXW &startupInfo);
            Process(
                const std::wstring &&path,
                const std::wstring &arguments,
                LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes,
                LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes,
                bool inheritHandles, 
                DWORD creationFlags,
                LPVOID environment,
                const std::wstring &currentDirectory,
                const STARTUPINFOEXW &startupInfo);
            Process(
                const std::wstring &path,
                const std::wstring &&arguments,
                LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes,
                LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes,
                bool inheritHandles, 
                DWORD creationFlags,
                LPVOID environment,
                const std::wstring &currentDirectory,
                const STARTUPINFOEXW &startupInfo);
            Process(
                const std::wstring &path,
                const std::wstring &arguments,
                LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes,
                LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes,
                bool inheritHandles, 
                DWORD creationFlags,
                LPVOID environment,
                const std::wstring &&currentDirectory,
                const STARTUPINFOEXW &startupInfo);
            Process(
                const std::wstring &&path,
                const std::wstring &&arguments,
                LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes,
                LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes,
                bool inheritHandles, 
                DWORD creationFlags,
                LPVOID environment,
                const std::wstring &currentDirectory,
                const STARTUPINFOEXW &startupInfo);
            Process(
                const std::wstring &path,
                const std::wstring &&arguments,
                LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes,
                LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes,
                bool inheritHandles, 
                DWORD creationFlags,
                LPVOID environment,
                const std::wstring &&currentDirectory,
                const STARTUPINFOEXW &startupInfo);
            Process(
                const std::wstring &&path,
                const std::wstring &arguments,
                LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes,
                LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes,
                bool inheritHandles, 
                DWORD creationFlags,
                LPVOID environment,
                const std::wstring &&currentDirectory,
                const STARTUPINFOEXW &startupInfo);
            Process(Process &&other);
            ~Process();

            void create();
            void terminate(UINT exitCode);
            bool awaitTermination(DWORD milliseconds, DWORD &exitCode);
            void resume();

            inline bool awaitTermination(DWORD milliseconds)
            {
                DWORD exitCode;

                return awaitTermination(milliseconds, exitCode);
            }

            inline bool isCreated() const
            {
                return this->created;
            }

            inline const std::wstring &getPath() const
            {
                return this->path;
            }

            inline const std::wstring &getArguments() const
            {
                return this->arguments;
            }

            inline const LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES getProcessAttributes() const
            {
                return this->processAttributes;
            }

            inline const LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES getThreadAttributes() const
            {
                return this->threadAttributes;
            }

            inline bool getInheritHandles() const
            {
                return this->inheritHandles;
            }

            inline DWORD getCreationFlags() const
            {
                return this->creationFlags;
            }

            inline const LPVOID getEnvironment() const
            {
                return this->environment;
            }

            inline const std::wstring &getCurrentDirectory() const
            {
                return this->currentDirectory;
            }

            inline const STARTUPINFOEXW &getStartupInfo() const
            {
                return this->startupInfo;
            }

            inline const PROCESS_INFORMATION &getProcessInformation() const
            {
                return this->processInformation;
            }

            inline DWORD getProcessId() const
            {
                return this->processInformation.dwProcessId;
            }

            inline DWORD getThreadId() const
            {
                return this->processInformation.dwThreadId;
            }

            inline HANDLE getProcessHandle() const
            {
                return this->processInformation.hProcess;
            }

            inline HANDLE getThreadHandle() const
            {
                return this->processInformation.hThread;
            }

        private:
            Process(const Process &other) = delete;
            Process &operator=(const Process &other) = delete;
            Process &operator=(const Process &&other) = delete;

            void init(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes);
            void cleanup();

            bool created;
            std::wstring path;
            std::wstring arguments;
            LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes;
            LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes;
            bool inheritHandles;
            DWORD creationFlags;
            LPVOID environment;
            std::wstring currentDirectory;
            STARTUPINFOEXW startupInfo;
            PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;
    };
}
```

*Process.cpp*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Process.h"

#include "Util.h"

namespace Shared
{
    Process::Process(
        const std::wstring &path,
        const std::wstring &arguments,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes,
        bool inheritHandles,
        DWORD creationFlags,
        LPVOID environment,
        const std::wstring &currentDirectory,
        const STARTUPINFOEXW &startupInfo) :
        created(false),
        path(path),
        arguments(arguments),
        processAttributes(NULL),
        threadAttributes(NULL),
        inheritHandles(inheritHandles),
        creationFlags(creationFlags),
        environment(environment),
        currentDirectory(currentDirectory),
        startupInfo(startupInfo),
        processInformation()
    {
        init(processAttributes, threadAttributes);
    }

    Process::Process(
        const std::wstring &&path,
        const std::wstring &&arguments,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes,
        bool inheritHandles,
        DWORD creationFlags,
        LPVOID environment,
        const std::wstring &&currentDirectory,
        const STARTUPINFOEXW &startupInfo) :
        created(false),
        path(std::forward<const std::wstring>(path)),
        arguments(std::forward<const std::wstring>(arguments)),
        processAttributes(NULL),
        threadAttributes(NULL),
        inheritHandles(inheritHandles),
        creationFlags(creationFlags),
        environment(environment),
        currentDirectory(std::forward<const std::wstring>(currentDirectory)),
        startupInfo(startupInfo),
        processInformation()
    {
        init(processAttributes, threadAttributes);
    }

    Process::Process(
        const std::wstring &&path,
        const std::wstring &arguments,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes,
        bool inheritHandles,
        DWORD creationFlags,
        LPVOID environment,
        const std::wstring &currentDirectory,
        const STARTUPINFOEXW &startupInfo) :
        created(false),
        path(std::forward<const std::wstring>(path)),
        arguments(arguments),
        processAttributes(NULL),
        threadAttributes(NULL),
        inheritHandles(inheritHandles),
        creationFlags(creationFlags),
        environment(environment),
        currentDirectory(currentDirectory),
        startupInfo(startupInfo),
        processInformation()
    {
        init(processAttributes, threadAttributes);
    }

    Process::Process(
        const std::wstring &path,
        const std::wstring &&arguments,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes,
        bool inheritHandles,
        DWORD creationFlags,
        LPVOID environment,
        const std::wstring &currentDirectory,
        const STARTUPINFOEXW &startupInfo) :
        created(false),
        path(path),
        arguments(std::forward<const std::wstring>(arguments)),
        processAttributes(NULL),
        threadAttributes(NULL),
        inheritHandles(inheritHandles),
        creationFlags(creationFlags),
        environment(environment),
        currentDirectory(currentDirectory),
        startupInfo(startupInfo),
        processInformation()
    {
        init(processAttributes, threadAttributes);
    }

    Process::Process(
        const std::wstring &path,
        const std::wstring &arguments,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes,
        bool inheritHandles,
        DWORD creationFlags,
        LPVOID environment,
        const std::wstring &&currentDirectory,
        const STARTUPINFOEXW &startupInfo) :
        created(false),
        path(path),
        arguments(arguments),
        processAttributes(NULL),
        threadAttributes(NULL),
        inheritHandles(inheritHandles),
        creationFlags(creationFlags),
        environment(environment),
        currentDirectory(std::forward<const std::wstring>(currentDirectory)),
        startupInfo(startupInfo),
        processInformation()
    {
        init(processAttributes, threadAttributes);
    }

    Process::Process(
        const std::wstring &&path,
        const std::wstring &&arguments,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes,
        bool inheritHandles,
        DWORD creationFlags,
        LPVOID environment,
        const std::wstring &currentDirectory,
        const STARTUPINFOEXW &startupInfo) :
        created(false),
        path(std::forward<const std::wstring>(path)),
        arguments(std::forward<const std::wstring>(arguments)),
        processAttributes(NULL),
        threadAttributes(NULL),
        inheritHandles(inheritHandles),
        creationFlags(creationFlags),
        environment(environment),
        currentDirectory(currentDirectory),
        startupInfo(startupInfo),
        processInformation()
    {
        init(processAttributes, threadAttributes);
    }

    Process::Process(
        const std::wstring &path,
        const std::wstring &&arguments,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes,
        bool inheritHandles,
        DWORD creationFlags,
        LPVOID environment,
        const std::wstring &&currentDirectory,
        const STARTUPINFOEXW &startupInfo) :
        created(false),
        path(path),
        arguments(std::forward<const std::wstring>(arguments)),
        processAttributes(NULL),
        threadAttributes(NULL),
        inheritHandles(inheritHandles),
        creationFlags(creationFlags),
        environment(environment),
        currentDirectory(std::forward<const std::wstring>(currentDirectory)),
        startupInfo(startupInfo),
        processInformation()
    {
        init(processAttributes, threadAttributes);
    }

    Process::Process(
        const std::wstring &&path,
        const std::wstring &arguments,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes,
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes,
        bool inheritHandles,
        DWORD creationFlags,
        LPVOID environment,
        const std::wstring &&currentDirectory,
        const STARTUPINFOEXW &startupInfo) :
        created(false),
        path(std::forward<const std::wstring>(path)),
        arguments(arguments),
        processAttributes(NULL),
        threadAttributes(NULL),
        inheritHandles(inheritHandles),
        creationFlags(creationFlags),
        environment(environment),
        currentDirectory(std::forward<const std::wstring>(currentDirectory)),
        startupInfo(startupInfo),
        processInformation()
    {
        init(processAttributes, threadAttributes);
    }

    Process::Process(Process &&other) :
        created(other.created),
        path(other.path),
        arguments(other.arguments),
        processAttributes(other.processAttributes),
        threadAttributes(other.threadAttributes),
        inheritHandles(other.inheritHandles),
        creationFlags(other.creationFlags),
        environment(other.environment),
        currentDirectory(other.currentDirectory),
        startupInfo(other.startupInfo),
        processInformation(other.processInformation)
    {
        other.processAttributes = NULL;
        other.threadAttributes = NULL;
        other.processInformation.hProcess = NULL;
        other.processInformation.hThread = NULL;
    }

    Process::~Process()
    {
        if (this->processAttributes != NULL)
        {
            delete this->processAttributes->lpSecurityDescriptor;
        }

        if (this->threadAttributes != NULL)
        {
            delete this->threadAttributes->lpSecurityDescriptor;
        }

        delete this->processAttributes;
        delete this->threadAttributes;

        if (this->startupInfo.lpAttributeList != NULL)
        {
            DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(this->startupInfo.lpAttributeList);
        }

        if (this->created)
        {
            CloseHandle(this->processInformation.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(this->processInformation.hThread);
        }
    }

    void Process::create()
    {
        if (this->created)
        {
            EXCEPTION("Already created");
        }

        wchar_t *arguments = NULL;
        if (!this->arguments.empty())
        {
            std::size_t argumentsLength = this->arguments.length() + 1;
            arguments = new wchar_t[argumentsLength];
            ZeroMemory(arguments, argumentsLength * sizeof(wchar_t));
            wcscpy_s(arguments, argumentsLength, this->arguments.c_str());
        }

        if (CreateProcessW(this->path.empty() ? NULL : this->path.c_str(), arguments, this->processAttributes, this->threadAttributes, this->inheritHandles, this->creationFlags, this->environment, this->currentDirectory.empty() ? NULL : this->currentDirectory.c_str(), reinterpret_cast<LPSTARTUPINFOW>(&this->startupInfo), &this->processInformation) == FALSE)
        {
            delete[] arguments;

            EXCEPTION_LAST_ERROR("Failed CreateProcessW");
        }

        delete[] arguments;

        this->created = true;
    }

    void Process::terminate(UINT exitCode)
    {
        if (!this->created)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (TerminateProcess(this->processInformation.hProcess, exitCode) == FALSE)
        {
            EXCEPTION_LAST_ERROR("Failed TerminateProcess");
        }

        cleanup();
    }

    bool Process::awaitTermination(DWORD milliseconds, DWORD &exitCode)
    {
        if (!this->created)
        {
            EXCEPTION("Process not created");
        }

        DWORD waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(this->processInformation.hProcess, milliseconds);
        if (waitResult == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (waitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            DWORD eCode;
            if (GetExitCodeProcess(this->processInformation.hProcess, &eCode) == FALSE)
            {
                EXCEPTION_LAST_ERROR("Failed GetExitCodeProcess");
            }

            cleanup();

            exitCode = eCode;

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            EXCEPTION("Failed WaitForSingleObject\nWait result: %u", waitResult);
        }
    }

    void Process::resume()
    {
        if (!this->created)
        {
            EXCEPTION("Process not created");
        }

        if (ResumeThread(this->processInformation.hThread) == -1)
        {
            EXCEPTION_LAST_ERROR("Failed ResumeThread");
        }
    }

    void Process::init(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes)
    {
        if (processAttributes != NULL)
        {
            PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR securityDescriptor = NULL;
            if (processAttributes->lpSecurityDescriptor != NULL)
            {
                securityDescriptor = new SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR();
                memcpy(securityDescriptor, processAttributes->lpSecurityDescriptor, sizeof(SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR));
            }

            this->processAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            memcpy(this->processAttributes, processAttributes, sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));
            this->processAttributes->lpSecurityDescriptor = securityDescriptor;
        }

        if (threadAttributes != NULL)
        {
            PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR securityDescriptor = NULL;
            if (threadAttributes->lpSecurityDescriptor != NULL)
            {
                securityDescriptor = new SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR();
                memcpy(securityDescriptor, threadAttributes->lpSecurityDescriptor, sizeof(SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR));
            }

            this->threadAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            memcpy(this->threadAttributes, threadAttributes, sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));
            this->threadAttributes->lpSecurityDescriptor = securityDescriptor;
        }

        this->creationFlags |= EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT;

        ZeroMemory(&this->processInformation, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    }

    void Process::cleanup()
    {
        if (CloseHandle(this->processInformation.hProcess) == FALSE || CloseHandle(this->processInformation.hThread) == FALSE)
        {
            EXCEPTION_LAST_ERROR("Failed CloseHandle");
        }

        ZeroMemory(&this->processInformation, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

        this->created = false;
    }
}
```

*RegistryKey.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

namespace Shared
{
    class RegistryKey
    {
        public:
            RegistryKey(HKEY key, const std::wstring &subKey, DWORD options, REGSAM samDesired);
            RegistryKey(HKEY key, const std::wstring &&subKey, DWORD options, REGSAM samDesired);
            RegistryKey(RegistryKey &&other);
            RegistryKey &operator=(RegistryKey &&other);
            ~RegistryKey();

            std::wstring getRegSZ(const std::wstring &subKey, const std::wstring &valueName) const;
            DWORD getRegDword(const std::wstring &valueName) const;
            void regNotifyChangeKeyValue(bool watchSubTree, DWORD notifyFilter, HANDLE eventHandle, bool asynchronous) const;

            inline HKEY getKey() const
            {
                return this->key;
            }

            inline const std::wstring &getSubKey() const
            {
                return this->subKey;
            }

            inline DWORD getOptions() const
            {
                return this->options;
            }

            inline REGSAM getSamDesired() const
            {
                return this->samDesired;
            }

        private:
            RegistryKey(const RegistryKey &other) = delete;
            RegistryKey &operator=(const RegistryKey &other) = delete;

            void init();
            void close();

            HKEY keyHandle;
            HKEY key;
            std::wstring subKey;
            DWORD options;
            REGSAM samDesired;
    };
}
```

*RegistryKey.cpp*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "RegistryKey.h"

#include "Util.h"

namespace Shared
{
    RegistryKey::RegistryKey(HKEY key, const std::wstring &subKey, DWORD options, REGSAM samDesired) :
        keyHandle(NULL),
        key(key),
        subKey(subKey),
        options(options),
        samDesired(samDesired)
    {
        init();
    }

    RegistryKey::RegistryKey(HKEY key, const std::wstring &&subKey, DWORD options, REGSAM samDesired) :
        keyHandle(NULL),
        key(key),
        subKey(std::forward<const std::wstring>(subKey)),
        options(options),
        samDesired(samDesired)
    {
        init();
    }

    RegistryKey::RegistryKey(RegistryKey &&other) :
        keyHandle(other.keyHandle),
        key(other.key),
        subKey(other.subKey),
        options(other.options),
        samDesired(other.samDesired)
    {
        other.keyHandle = NULL;
    }

    RegistryKey &RegistryKey::operator=(RegistryKey &&other)
    {
        close();

        this->keyHandle = other.keyHandle;
        this->key = other.key;
        this->subKey = other.subKey;
        this->options = other.options;
        this->samDesired = other.samDesired;

        other.keyHandle = NULL;

        return (*this);
    }

    RegistryKey::~RegistryKey()
    {
        try
        {
            close();
        }
        catch (std::runtime_error)
        {

        }
    }

    std::wstring RegistryKey::getRegSZ(const std::wstring &subKey, const std::wstring &valueName) const
    {
        if ((this->samDesired & KEY_QUERY_VALUE) != KEY_QUERY_VALUE)
        {
            EXCEPTION("This registry key handle does not have KEY_QUERY_VALUE rights");
        }

        std::size_t bufferSize = MAX_PATH;
        wchar_t *buffer = new wchar_t[bufferSize];
        DWORD bufferByteSize = static_cast<DWORD>(bufferSize * sizeof(wchar_t));

        LSTATUS registryGetValueStatus = RegGetValueW(this->keyHandle, subKey.empty() ? NULL : subKey.c_str(), valueName.empty() ? NULL : valueName.c_str(), RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(buffer), &bufferByteSize);

        while (registryGetValueStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            delete[] buffer;

            if (registryGetValueStatus == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
            {
                bufferSize *= 2;
                buffer = new wchar_t[bufferSize];
                bufferByteSize = static_cast<DWORD>(bufferSize * sizeof(wchar_t));

                registryGetValueStatus = RegGetValueW(this->keyHandle, subKey.empty() ? NULL : subKey.c_str(), valueName.empty() ? NULL : valueName.c_str(), RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(buffer), &bufferByteSize);
            }
            else
            {
                EXCEPTION("Failed RegGetValueW\nLSTATUS: %d", registryGetValueStatus);
            }
        }

        std::wstring arkInstallPath(buffer);
        delete[] buffer;

        return arkInstallPath;
    }

    DWORD RegistryKey::getRegDword(const std::wstring &valueName) const
    {
        if ((this->samDesired & KEY_QUERY_VALUE) != KEY_QUERY_VALUE)
        {
            EXCEPTION("This registry key handle does not have KEY_QUERY_VALUE rights");
        }

        DWORD result;
        DWORD dataSize = sizeof(DWORD);
        LSTATUS status = RegQueryValueExW(this->keyHandle, valueName.empty() ? NULL : valueName.c_str(), NULL, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&result), &dataSize);
        if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            EXCEPTION("Failed RegQueryValueExW\nLSTATUS: %d", status);
        }

        return result;
    }

    void RegistryKey::regNotifyChangeKeyValue(bool watchSubTree, DWORD notifyFilter, HANDLE eventHandle, bool asynchronous) const
    {
        if ((this->samDesired & KEY_NOTIFY) != KEY_NOTIFY)
        {
            EXCEPTION("This registry key handle does not have KEY_NOTIFY  rights");
        }

        LSTATUS result = RegNotifyChangeKeyValue(this->keyHandle, watchSubTree ? TRUE : FALSE, notifyFilter, eventHandle, asynchronous ? TRUE : FALSE);
        if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            EXCEPTION("Failed RegNotifyChangeKeyValue\nLSTATUS: %d", result);
        }
    }

    void RegistryKey::init()
    {
        LSTATUS registryOpenStatus = RegOpenKeyExW(this->key, this->subKey.empty() ? NULL : this->subKey.c_str(), this->options, this->samDesired, &this->keyHandle);
        if (registryOpenStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            EXCEPTION("Failed RegOpenKeyExW\nLSTATUS: %d", registryOpenStatus);
        }
    }

    void RegistryKey::close()
    {
        if (this->keyHandle == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }

        LSTATUS registryCloseStatus = RegCloseKey(this->keyHandle);
        if (registryCloseStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            EXCEPTION("Failed RegCloseKey\nSystem error code: %d", registryCloseStatus);
        }

        this->keyHandle = NULL;
    }
}
```

*SteamClient.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>

namespace BattleyeInjector
{
    class SteamClient final
    {
        public:
            SteamClient();

            void start();
            void startAndAwaitLogin(int maxTryCount);

        private:
            DWORD getActiveUserId();
    };
}
```

*SteamClient.cpp*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SteamClient.h"

#include <string>

#include <RegistryKey.h>
#include <Process.h>
#include <Util.h>

namespace BattleyeInjector
{
    static const HKEY STEAM_KEY = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;

    static const std::wstring STEAM_INSTALL_PATH_SUB_KEY = L"SOFTWARE\\Valve\\Steam";
    static const std::wstring STEAM_INSTALL_PATH_KEY_NAME = L"SteamExe";

    static const std::wstring STEAM_ACTIVE_PROCESS_SUB_KEY = L"SOFTWARE\\Valve\\Steam\\ActiveProcess";
    static const std::wstring STEAM_ACTIVE_USER_KEY_NAME = L"ActiveUser";

    SteamClient::SteamClient()
    {

    }

    void SteamClient::start()
    {
        Shared::RegistryKey registryKey(STEAM_KEY, STEAM_INSTALL_PATH_SUB_KEY, 0, KEY_READ);
        const std::wstring steamInstallPath = registryKey.getRegSZ(L"", STEAM_INSTALL_PATH_KEY_NAME);

        STARTUPINFOEXW startupInfo;
        ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFOEXW));

        startupInfo.StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOEXW);

        Shared::Process steamProcess(steamInstallPath, L"", NULL, NULL, false, 0, NULL, L"", startupInfo);
        steamProcess.create();
    }

    void SteamClient::startAndAwaitLogin(int maxTryCount)
    {
        if (maxTryCount <= 0)
        {
            EXCEPTION("maxTryCount is invalid");
        }

        if (getActiveUserId() != 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        HANDLE eventHandle = CreateEventW(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
        if (eventHandle == NULL)
        {
            EXCEPTION_LAST_ERROR("Failed CreateEventW");
        }

        try
        {
            Shared::RegistryKey registryKey(STEAM_KEY, STEAM_ACTIVE_PROCESS_SUB_KEY, 0, KEY_READ);
            for (int x = 0; x < maxTryCount; x++)
            {
                registryKey.regNotifyChangeKeyValue(false, REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_SET, eventHandle, true);

                start();

                DWORD waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(eventHandle, INFINITE);
                if (waitResult != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                {
                    EXCEPTION("Failed WaitForSingleObject\nWaitResult: %u", waitResult);
                }

                if (getActiveUserId() != 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (ResetEvent(eventHandle) == FALSE)
                {
                    EXCEPTION_LAST_ERROR("Failed ResetEvent");
                }
            }

            EXCEPTION("Failed await login to steam");
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            CloseHandle(eventHandle);

            throw;
        }
    }

    DWORD SteamClient::getActiveUserId()
    {
        Shared::RegistryKey registryKey(STEAM_KEY, STEAM_ACTIVE_PROCESS_SUB_KEY, 0, KEY_READ);

        return registryKey.getRegDword(STEAM_ACTIVE_USER_KEY_NAME);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. I will have a look on it in some days and will translate it to C# and post the result here.

Comment: @chris579 np. The game for which I'm using this doesn't auto start steam either and just plain closes without any message if steam isn't started. So I came up with this solution while spitting through the registry hehe.

Comment: @chris579 I ran into a problem with this solution today. It seems that sometimes when Steam exits it leaves those registry values to whatever they were and not reset them to 0. So keep that in mind when using this.

Comment: How is this better than using the Steam actual API exactly supposed to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using this for a game, if I am correct you need the steamworks sdk from valve. The only way you can get the official SDK is by passing the greenlight process on steam. You can however use this, https://steamworks.github.io/ . Hope this helps you.

Comment: Not really. As already pointed out in the comments above it's an external tool for a game so I won't use the steamworks api I already found. However thanks for the hint.

Comment: It doesn't have to be used for a game, you can use this for any c# application.   https://github.com/rlabrecque/Steamworks.NET/tree/master/Standalone   I didn't see that branch when i last posted.

Comment: I know but it's too heavy for me to use it. All examples are written for Unity and the documentation is quite small.

Comment: You're only other option would be making a managed c++ plugin for your c# application that uses ReadProcessMemory. Be careful though if don't know what you're doing you are going to get vac banned pretty fast with this.

Comment: I know that there are also other possibilities. The package you mentioned is also not reading directly from the memory...

Comment: The package I mentioned is just a C# wrapper for the original c++ steam works released by valve. If you look at the nativetypes.cs file you will see where it imports the methods from the c++ dll. There really isn't any other way to detect if a user is logged in to steam other then using the api that steam provides you or by reading the memory. What exactly are you trying to do with your arma 3 launcher? There might be other ways to achieve it without checking their logged in status on steam.

Comment: Well it's just a nice to have thing. It would also work without. Just want to notify the user that Steam is not started or not logged in.